# How to mark a FCM notification as being opened in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I integrated FirebaseMessaging into my Flutter app and I am able to see campaign notifications both in foreground and background displayed.

But for some reason the "Opens" count in the FCM console is always 0.
Even when I click in my App immediately upon arrival on the message which opens the App.

[image]

Is there some special action required to tell Firebase that the user has opened the notification?

Answer (score 1):

FCM notifications are only marked as opened in the Reports tab in the Firebase Console when the notification is opened when the app is in the background.

> Opens — The user opened the notification message. Reported only for
> notifications received when the app is in the background.
>
> Source: [Firebase | Understanding message delivery | Message delivery reports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=web#:%7E:text=Opens%20%E2%80%94%20The%20user%20opened%20the%20notification%20message.%20Reported%20only%20for%20notifications%20received%20when%20the%20app%20is%20in%20the%20background.)

Comment: yes but in my case the notification is not marked as opened even if it was opened when the app was in background...

Comment: On what platform does this occur? @finisinfinitatis

Comment: I am using Android

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone on the Flutter app :

Found the root cause. Make FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to true in info.list

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <true/>
```

Tested recently and it's working.

[image: Firebase console screenshot]

Note that this **Opnes** count shows values after a few hours. So to test if it is working make your app debug mode and see it on the debug console on Firebase. If **notification_open** analytics come or not (this is Firebase automatic analytics call)

[image: Firebase console screenshot for debug view]

To make iOS app debug mode do this:

On X-code > Product > Scheme > Edit scheme
Arguments > Add **-FIRDebugEnabled**